# Pandas - convert value as type string to float

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime

In my df I have some values set up as `dtype(str)`

```
      x
  27:47
  13:45
  10:45
```

And I would like to convert them to `float`, ending up with:

```
      x
  27.47
  13.45
  10.45
```

---

How do I do this?

Comment: but `27 mins, 47 seconds` is not `27.47` minutes?

Comment: it can be '.', no problem

Comment: I mean 1 minute = 60 seconds, so `47 seconds` is about `.76` minute, not `.47` minute.

Comment: the name does not matter, really, just the conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can do:

```
df['x'] = df['x'].str.replace(':','.').astype(float)
```

Output:

```
       x
0  27.47
1  13.45
2  10.45
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['x'] = df['x'].replace(to_replace=":",value=".").astype(float)
```

Comment: `.str` is needed.

Comment: Nope. Beacuse this is Pandas .replace() method

Comment: well, the solution below worked and the only difference is that one....

Comment: yes...I made sure to pass `df.x.astype(str)`...but somehow it only works with .str before replace

Comment: For earlier me it worked without `.str`, still can't figure out what's the cause